# How can you unlock an iOS device using private frameworks?

Tags: ios, ios4, jailbreak, iphone-privateapi

I haven't dabbled in iOS private frameworks until now, when I randomly wanted to make an app which could lock & unlock the device..

An iOS hacker friend of mine pointed me to **GraphicsServices.framework** and `GSEvent.h` - there I found `GSEventLockDevice()`, which locks the iOS device -> I can't seem to find any other similar function to **unlock** the device, other than potentially simulating a lock button press and then simulating the touch drag on the "**Slide to unlock**" bar.

Does anybody know of a non-touch-simulation method to unlock the device - or - can anyone point me in the right direction at all?

Answer (score 2):

Check out rpetrichs' private framework headers:
https://github.com/rpetrich/iphoneheaders/

I believe in SpringBoard/SBUIController.h there's a lock method, hope that helps ;)

Answer (score 1):

If you have any experience in IDA you could look at the actual implementation of the "Slide to Unlock" button: that will give you the answer for sure.